# AsycTask thread inside doInBackground runs after PostExecution has started

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask and there are threads running inside the doInBackground method, isn't the purpose of AsyncTask is to let all the code finish executing inside the doInBackground and THEN go to PostExecute? Then why is it that some of my threads are running after the code block in PostExecution has started?

What should I do to solve this problem?

```
public class myActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    new myTask().execute();
}


class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

   Boolean success;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        success = true
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Callback callback = new Callback() {
                 public void successCallback(String name, Object response) {
                                                                }
                 public void errorCallback(String name, error) {
                        success = false;}
            };
        } catch (Exception e) {
            success = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        if (success == true){
              // do something
        }
    }
 }
}
```

It is inside the error callback, that I want the success field to change to false. But the error callback runs after the postExecute method.

Comment: Post your code. This question is unclear.

Comment: The question received negative response, yet I did not get any useful suggestions

Answer (score 3):

I think that you misunderstand the threading model.

AsyncTask does indeed execute doInBackground first, on a background thread, and then executes onPostExecute on the foreground thread, passing it the result from doInBackground.

However, from the wording of your question, it sounds like you are starting new threads from doInBackground. I'm sure that doInBackground does indeed complete before onPostExecute starts, but there is nothing that would cause the AsyncTask to wait for your additional threads to complete as well.

Edit:

It looks like you could skip the AayncTask altogether. The reason that you have callbacks is probably that method is already asynchronous

But note that you are only creating the callback, never using it. Perhaps you just left that part out?

Comment: thank you ! yes, I am starting some new threads in AsyncTask's doInBackground()... what can I do to solve this problem, ill add code to demonstrate the problem